# Python decorator staticmethod object not callable

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

Hi I'm trying to create a decorator but I'm getting an error of **staticmethod object not callable** below is my code

```
from db.persistence import S3Mediator
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import logging
from functools import wraps

Base = declarative_base()

def s3(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            s3client = S3Mediator.get_s3_connection()
            kwargs["s3client"] = s3client
            retval = func(*args, **kwargs) #### an error is raised here
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        return retval
    return wrapper
```

And here is the mediator that instantiate the s3 object

```
import boto3
import logging

class S3Mediator(object):
    s3_client = None

    def __init__(self, host, access_key, secret):
        self.client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id= access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key= secret
        )

        S3Mediator.s3_client = self.client

    @staticmethod
    def get_s3_connection():
        return S3Mediator.s3_client
```

Now **S3Mediator is already instantiate at the app.py** now I'm trying to use this decorator as

```
@s3
@staticmethod
def s3_connect(s3client):
  # code don't reach here. An error is thrown
  # do something here
```

[image]

Any idea why its returning a **staticmethod object not callable** and how to fix this

Comment: You're trying to make a standalone function into a static method?

Comment: As @khelwood says, you forgot to indent your get_s3_connection function. As defined the function is not part of the S3Mediator class

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what I'm doing as this is almost the exact code on our current project. What is the best approach to do this? I'm trying to make the s3 connection persistent all throughout the application

Comment: @Vyko sorry typo error. But indentation on my code is correct

Comment: What is the point of `except Exception as e: raise e` ?

Comment: None really its just if something wen't wrong :D

Comment: Don't put screenshots of text in your question. Put the stack trace as text.

Answer (score 5):

Ok found the cause of the problem. I put the **@staticmethod** below my decorator that's why my decorator is thinking that all method of the decorator is static. I just change the

```
@s3
@staticmethod
def s3_connect(s3client):
  # code don't reach here. An error is thrown
  # do something here
```

to this

```
@staticmethod
@s3
def s3_connect(s3client):
  # code don't reach here. An error is thrown
  # do something here
```